# Checking if a m3u8 URL is broken using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to determine if an m3u8 URL is broken or not. I test with two different URLs, one that is online and one that is offline. For both cases, my javascript function doesn't alert me that file is found or not and firefox debugs doesn't give me any error but status variable always shows 0. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Edit:

```
for offline url i get this header response(in httpfox developer tool) :HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
for online url i get this header response(in httpfox developer tool) :HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Code:

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function testFunction() {


    //m="http://someothersite.com/offline.m3u8";
    m="http://somesite.com/workingfile.m3u8";

    //now we checking if the file exist

    UrlExists(m, function(status){
     alert('status:'+status);
        if(status === 200){
           // file was found
           alert('file found'+m);

        }
        else if(status === 404){
           // 404 not found
           alert('file not found'+m);


        }
    });

    function UrlExists(url, cb){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:      url,
            dataType: 'text',
            type:     'GET',
            complete:  function(xhr){
            alert(+xhr.status);
                if(typeof cb === 'function')
                   cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);

            }
        });
    }


    }// end of main

    </script>




    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="testFunction()">Click me</button>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work if you are using external URL's as CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) will kick in and will stop you as you are not on the same domain.

**Working version:** local files only

```
UrlExists('/path/file.php', function(status){
    if(status === 200){
       alert('file found');
    }
    else if(status === 404){
       alert('file not found');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, there isnt a valid way of doing this through Javascript. However, you can conduct this through backend functionality e.g. PHP

```
$file = 'http://www.othername.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

If you build this into a php function and then use your Ajax functionality to pass the URL through to the PHP for validation, and then return back a response - it should work.

**Edit: Curl Example**

```
$mainUrl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($mainUrl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($mainUrl);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($mainUrl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    echo "404 Error";
}else if($httpCode == 200){
    echo "200 Error";
}else{
    echo "all good - sort off...";
}

curl_close($mainUrl);
```

Here is the Curl option - Now the way i would do it (and i really had to do it...) is looping through each and every single URL on the page (in js) and sending it as an object to PHP (through Ajax). With PHP, i would use the above CURL functionality to confirm which ones are broken (either with a 1 or 0) and then send a response back.

Comment: Thanks for reply. for image files the javascript works ! why the cross domain is not an issue there ?i didn't get any cross domain error on firebug for m3u8 links ! Furthermore, if i use php for a list of urls does it consume lots of resource on server side ? for get_headers to work what needs to be enabled in server side ?

Comment: With images its different, so with images you can use `onerror="javascriptFunction()"` right within the image. Now with images, they need to load directly from its URL on `pageload`. With links, they are just static strings until a user clicks on it and then are taken to the destination. Its an ajax call right so double check on network tab to see what the response you are getting is... Yes memory usage will be high but dont think that it will deplete your server. There are multiple ways to check whether a link is live (`get_headers` was an example, `curl` is another)

Comment: i tried get_header code of you but i didnt get anything printed ? how to check if the server that i test on allow get_header method ? you think get_ header method is better then curl ?

Comment: @user1788736 updated with Curl example. The `get_header` code will only return a `true` or a `false` within the variables. Its what you do outside of that if statement with that variable. `get_header` is good and so is `curl` (they both have their places) so i have placed both examples

Comment: i tested your php solution for file that doesn't exist the script takes for ever to stop and i get 0 for $httpcode=0!(works well for m3u8 that is downloadable and script stops fast and shows 200) is there a way to timeout after few seconds and we output to user that m3u8 url is broken?